# Elasticsearch scroll when using a simple HTTP POST method in a C# console program

Tags: c#, json, elasticsearch, scroll

I have a C# console program which is retrieving a large amount of data in raw JSON format. This work well using this code:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
    client.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(credentials));
    string myDataResult = client.UploadString(url, "POST", myQuery);

    <result handling code>
}
```

At the moment there is no maximum size, but in a short while there will be a limit of 3000. This means I have to use scrolling to get all the data I need. I have been reading about NEST, but I hope to avoid it. I just need the raw JSON output my request i producing. Any simple ways to extend my code so it uses scrolling?

Best regards, Brian

Comment: NEST is just a wrpper around the rest API, so you can use any C# rest client to accomplish the same. With scroll API you just need to pass the page size and TTL with the initial request and the scroll Id returned with subsequent requests,  rest API details here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html

Answer (score 0):

You will need to maintain and pass in to your request what page you're requesting, and the limit (number of items you want returned).

I would take a look at the ElasticSearch API docs for examples of how the request body would look. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html

Going off of this, it looks like "from" would be the page you're requesting, "size" would be the limit or number of items you want.